# How to calculate average in mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

My schema looks like

```js
point: { type: Number, default: 0 },
effort: { type: Number, default: 0 },
note: { type: String },
dateRated: {type: Date},
createDate: {type:Date},
dateInfoId: {type: String}
```

I'm trying to calculate average of point and effort by passing certain `_id`'s

My code looks like

```js
frequencies = ["mongo object id"];
Frequency.aggregate([{
    $project: {
        _id: {
            $in: ['$_id', frequencies]
        },
        point: {
            $ne: ['$point', 0]
        }
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: {
            $in: ['$_id', frequencies]
        },
        average: {
            $avg: "$point"
        },
        effort: {
            $avg: "$effort"
        }
    }
}], (err, result) => {});
```

But it always returns `[ { _id: false, average: null, effort: null } ]`. What should I do to calculate the average of my points and effort?

Comment: $match instead of $project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to be like this :

```
Frequency.aggregate([{
    $match: {
        _id: {
            $in: frequencies
        }, point: { $ne: 0 }
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: null,
        average: {
            $avg: "$point"
        },
        effort: {
            $avg: "$effort"
        }
    }
}])
```

Here `$match` would retain only the documents that match with passed `frequencies` and where `point != 0`, then after all you need is to iterate through all documents to get the average of required two fields, So `$group` helps to do that, where `_id: null` or `_id: ''` will iterate through all of the leftover documents, you no need to specify a filter again in group stage.